# Kafka Should Number of Consumer Threads equal number of Topic Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Pretend you determined that you wanted to use exactly 8 consumer threads for your application.

Would there be any difference in processing if a Kafka topic was set up as having 8 partitions vs 16 partitions?

In the first case, each thread is assigned to a single partition with twice the data, and in the second case each thread is assigned to two partitions with half the data each. It seems to me that there is no difference between these two setups.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that, on the consumer side there could be a difference, if your threads are not CPU-constrained (and network is not at capacity).  Assuming infinite data on the Kafka broker, or a lagging consumer, since each thread is consuming from two partitions in your second example, the kafka broker is able to send more data than if each thread had only one partition assigned.  Kafka has a limit on the maximum amount of bytes that can be retrieved per fetch (`replica.fetch.max.bytes` in the config), so if you 2x the partitions, you can increase capacity, assuming the data is available.

When configured properly, and assuming ideal conditions, Kafka will serve data from page cache, so it can blast data down to consumers, and 90% of the time, the bottleneck will be the amount of partitions/available CPU on the consumer side.  In general, the more partitions you have, the faster you can consume from Kafka, until you are CPU or bandwidth constrained on the consumer, at which point it won't matter if you have more or less partitions, since you're consuming data as fast as you can anyway.

An additional thing to take into account is that there could be more consumer commits being sent back to the brokers, since there are now more partitions, which means some additional overhead/crosstalk in the cluster.  It's probably not 2x the commits, but probably higher than 1x the commits from the first scenario.

An important thing to remember is to, whenever possible, do the actual message processing on your consumer *off-thread*.  That is, do *not* process the inbound messages on the same thread that is consuming/polling from Kafka.  It might work at first, but you're going to start running into issues if your processing takes longer, there's a delay, huge volume increase on the inbound side, etc.  Whenever possible, throw the inbound messages on a queue, and let another thread worry about processing/parsing them.

Finally, you don't want to take this to the extreme, and configure 1000 partitions if you don't have to.  Each partition requires overhead on commits, zookeeper znodes, consumer rebalancing time, startup time, etc.  So, I would suggest benchmarking different scenarios, and seeing what works best for you.  In general, anything from 2-4 partitions per consumer thread has worked well for me in the past, even with very high message loads (topics with 50K+ messages per second, each ~1KB).